# aztfexport and exporting the whole resources of an API Management service

Tags: azure, terraform

The context: I have resource group, let's call it myRG.

myRG contains an API Mangement service let's call it APIM.

When I use aztfexport as below, I only get the API Mangement service properties in a TF form. I'm not getting all the "sub resources" contained in this APIM, like the APIs, operations, policies ... and so on.

```
aztfexport query -n "resourceGroup =~ 'myRG' and type contains 'Microsoft.ApiManagement'"
```

Same result when using

```
aztfexport resource <link_to_my_apim>
```

The only way to get all the resources i'm looking for is to execute

```
aztfexport resource-group myRG
```

I'm more looking for an explanation on how it works like this

Comment: By default, `aztfexport query` gives only the top level resources but not subsequent ones. To get all the resources, you need to use `aztfexport resource-group` as you already mentioned. But this may evolve any time so Instead of it, you can use `AzCLI` commands to retrieve all the apis and their operations within it. @fays

Comment: If that works for you, I can provide a detailed explanation with relevant commands. @fays

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi. I have two goals actually : 
1. export my API Management instance from a manually created instance into a TF code
2. create a replica of this same API Management instance in an another environemnt
I'll be pleased to read your explanations of course

Comment: Updated with explanation. @fays

Answer (score 0):

> Export my API Management instance from a manually created instance into a TF code:

There is no terraform export command in terraform infrastructure to export instance code directly from one to other. Instead as a workaround, I found a way which is detailed below.

- Go to your existed `API Management instance >> Automation >> Export template`.
- An API `JSON` template will be shown as below.
- Export the ARM template and save it with .Json extension and use it in the terraform code with [`azurerm_template_deployment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment#example-usage). Or you can deploy the same ARM template by making required changes using ARM itself.
- Once it is done, deploy the template accordingly.

[image]

Same as above, you can export the APIs under API Management service by visiting `APIs >> APIs >> Export` as shown below.

[image]

> Create a replica of this same API Management instance in another environment:

*Approach-1:*

Following the above given process, deploy the same configuration template by modifying the environment related variable in the template in the Portal itself.

[image]

[image]

*Approach-2:*

Alternatively, you can use [Terraform workspaces](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/workspaces) which manages multiple environment deployments of the same configuration. Refer the attached document for more relevant information.

*Approach-3:*

You can also backup and restore the API Management instance in the required environment using PowerShell commands.

[**Backup-AzApiManagement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/backup-azapimanagement?view=azps-11.2.0#examples) & [**Restore-AzApiManagement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.apimanagement/restore-azapimanagement?view=azps-11.1.0)

```
New-AzStorageAccount -StorageAccountName "newjstorage" -Location "eastUs" -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Type Standard_LRS
$Key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -StorageAccountName "newjstorage")[0].Value
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "newjstorage" -StorageAccountKey $Key
Backup-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "policyj" -StorageContext $Context -TargetContainerName "new"
```

[image]

*Reference:* [Blog](https://www.qovery.com/blog/how-to-manage-multiple-environments-with-terraform/) by @Romaric Philogène.